# Deleting a file with ajax javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a page where you can upload files and delete them.

My upload is working fine and my download also.
But i cant get my delete working, i want to have the delete using AJAX and a possible confirm box but when i click my button now it doesnt do anything.

The formatoverzicht.php and ajax.php are in the main folder and the files that need to be deleted are in a uploads folder in side the main folder.

Here is my code.

Formatoverzicht.php

```
<script src="/website/libraries/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-btn').click(function(filename) {
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { filename: filename },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'success') {
            $this = $(this).closest('tr');
            $this.remove();
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

The Button:

```
<button data-file="<?php echo $file ?>" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
```

Ajax.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['filename'])) {
   if (unlink(htmlentities( $_POST['filename']))) {
     echo "success";
   }
}
?>
```

I am trying to get this fixed for a couple of days now but it still doesnt work.

EDIT:

I am not using this code:

```
<script src="/website/libraries/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('.delete-btn').on('click',function() {
 filename=$(this).attr('data-file');
   $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { 'filename': filename },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'success') {
            $this = $(this).closest('tr');
            $this.remove();
        }
    }
});
})
});
</script>
```

and i now get: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.  as an error. But the code still doesnt delete or do anything.

Comment: and what is the return for the error of the Ajax?

Comment: Whats the actual problem ? is it atleast hitting  the target server script ?

Comment: did u able to get post data in php file?

Comment: when i click the button nothing happens, no error or something

Comment: did u added jquery file ?

Comment: yep jquery is added in a seperate script tag

Comment: aah, try using a different data name, instead of  `data: { filename: filename },`  with  this `data: { flname: filename },` ,and refer the same in your target server script

Comment: for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820540/delete-the-uploded-image-file-using-ajax-code

Comment: OP: Your php unlink code, could really ruin your day.

Comment: you should never, ever, allow the user to specify the actual path of the file to delete.

Comment: this is a website for local use only, so i dont think it would be a problem if people could do that here.

Comment: i tryed all of the codes but it still deosnt do anything and doesnt give a warning. i tryd combining some of them but still no result.

Comment: do you even see a POST request in your javascript console?

Comment: in the chrome console i dont see anything exept the event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.     and where should i find the post falue if its not in the console.

Comment: don't worry about that deprecated warning. Are you running this with local files? This might just be a browser issue, where you're not allowed to request files this way. Try to run this under localhost, see if your ajax.php does get called...

Comment: @Reinder i am running this localhost, and i see that ajax.php is called with method POST. but nothing happens

Comment: Must have something to do with either 'unlink()' or 'htmlentities()' then. What is the output of the AJAX request if you comment out the 2nd PHP if statement and just output 'echo $_POST["filename"]'; and 'echo htmlentities($_POST["filename"])';
Check if that path is correct...

Comment: i tryed what you did, and i tryed to only put those 2 line in the ajax.php but it still doesnt do anything. i think there must be something wrong whit the ajax request or something there

Comment: what do you see if you remove all code in ajax.php and only put var_dump($_POST); in there. Check the response of the request in your javascript console

Comment: i was looking around in chromes F12 screen, and clicked on the ajax.php network request and then i saw in the response tap TestLighthouse.jpg ( i have the windows sample photos as test file) so i dont know why it adds a Test before the filename. maybe thats part of the problem

Comment: Thas was my guess too, the file name that's sent to ajax.php doesn't match the original filename anymore. Either through typo's or through a function like htmlentities()

Comment: When i do the var_dump i get array(1) {
  ["filename"]=>
  string(10) "Tulips.jpg"
}

Comment: in ajax.php there is an htmlentities, could that be a problem

Comment: Then Tulips.jpg is the file that will be deleted, and it has to be in the same directory as the executing ajax.php file...

Comment: so to fix it i should place ajax.php in side the uploads folder, or make something so that $file has the folder name in it.

Comment: yay, its deleting now only need it needs to refresh after it get answer from the ajax.php. thanks for the help.

Comment: Indeed; deleting is a filesystem action, so either use the full system path (or a relative path) or move ajax.php to your uploads folder. I've updated my answer with this info...

Comment: So, was any of the answers helpfull? Did you manage to solve this issue? Please update this SO item; maybe you can check 1 of the answers as 'correct'...

Answer (score 0):

It is because filename is totally undefined. You should use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-btn').click(function() {
 var filename = $(this).attr('data-file');
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { 'filename' : filename },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data == 'success') {
            $this = $(this).closest('tr');
            $this.remove();
        }
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
$('.delete-btn').click(function(filename)
```

be:

`$('.delete-btn').click(function(file)` ?

Or retrieve the filename inside the anonymous function like:

`$(this).attr('data-file');` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.delete-btn').on('click',function() {
    filename=$(this).attr('data-file');
     $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: { filename: filename },
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'success') {
                $this = $(this).closest('tr');
                $this.remove();
            }
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

try doing it on('click'), also your filename is not passed to function.

Comment: this one is still wrong, as you create data object based on variable not string...  should be `data: { 'filename' : filename }`... second thing is that it is not a good practice to use global variable in such a function, so use `var filename=$(".delete-btn").attr('data-file');`, and third... hardcoding button selector is wrong too, as there are probably more than one button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

HTML:

```
 <button data-file="<?php echo base64_encode($file); ?>" class="delete-btn">Delete</button>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['filename'])) {
    $file = base64_decode($_POST['filename']);

    if(is_file($file)){
       if (unlink($file)) {
         echo "success";
       }
     }else{
        echo "there is no file found (". $file.")";
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button click is not handled because the javascript is not triggered. You need to wrap your javascript in jQuery 'ready()' statement, like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your stuff 
});
```

Then you should set your filename variable, as suggested by the others, like so:

```
filename=$(this).attr('data-file');
```

instead of passing it directly to the function...

Also, check that the filename that is send to ajax.php matches the original filename. The path should also match off course, since deleting is a filesystem action. Either use the full system path when deleting (or a relative path) or make sure that ajax.php is inside the same directory as the file you want to delete